# Optimising speed of games on external SD card

Tags: apps, micro-sd, games

I have Nokia Lumia 720. I am playing Asphalt 8 and Six Guns games on it. This device has less internal memory and 512MB of RAM. I know this RAM is too low but Windows Phones are faster than android phones. The games used to stutter less when placed in internal memory.

But since I have moved them to external SD card these games are running really slow now. The game hangs in the middle of the gameplay.

Any fix or work around to get rid of this stuttering and glitches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed of game is directly proportional to the Class of sd card that we're using. Check the class of your sd card, mine is 10, games work good but there are occasional lags but they dont last long (the lags of course).

Sd card with classes 4 or 6 probably creates worst experience. Always buy a sd card with good Class.

Look at the below image I posted, about where to look for class of sd card.

[image]

Comment: Please do comment about your sd card class. Good day!

Comment: sure I'll check it and inform you

Comment: It's class 4. So does that mean I need  a class 10 cards for better performance?

Comment: So class 2 are worst and then 4 and 6? Right? @RanRaj

Comment: yes, class 8 are also good, and am amazed that you bought a class 2 sd card.

Comment: I have class 4 card not class 2 card. It's not that I bought it. I got it with device